# How can I get the value of selected Autocomplete in the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a following parent component:

```
<FormProvider {...formProps}> 
 <SearchRole
          name="roles"
          placeholder={"Search via Role Name"}
          options={rolesOptions}
          isLoading={isLoading}
        />
<Button label="search" disable = { // if the value from the above autocomplete not selected }  />
  <Button label="reset" disable = { // if the value is selected then set to empty }  />
</FormProvider>
```

SearchRole.jsx:

```
<FormGroup className="role-container__search-container__form-container">
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }) => (
          <Autocomplete
            id="role-list"
            disablePortal
            disableClearable={true}
            disableCloseOnSelect={false}
            options={options}
            PaperComponent={({ children }) => (
              <Paper
                style={{
                  boxShadow: "0px 10px 20px 0px #00000040",
                }}
              >
                {children}
              </Paper>
            )}
            renderOption={(props, option, { inputValue }, id) => {
              const matches = match(option?.label, inputValue, {
                insideWords: true,
              });
              const parts = parse(option?.label, matches);
              return (
                <ListItem key={option?.value} disablePadding {...props}>
                  <ListItemText
                    id={id}
                    primary={parts?.map((part, index) => (
                      <span
                        key={index}
                        style={{
                          fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400,
                        }}
                      >
                        {part.text}
                      </span>
                    ))}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              );
            }}
            loading={isLoading || !!options}
            renderInput={(params) => {
              return (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label={placeholder}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <SearchIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              );
            }}
            {...rest}
            onChange={(_, data) => {
              onChange(data);
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </FormGroup>
```

Now, I am trying to get the value of selected text in the parent component or I want to disable a button if this value is not selected ( a button which is in parent component ) and I am trying to reset this value to empty if selected. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Create one flag and Pass one method from parent component and set Flag on change in child component with that method,

In Parent:

```js
const [isRoleSelected, setIsRoleSelected] = useState(false);

return (
  <FormProvider {...formProps}> 
    <SearchRole
      setIsSelected={setIsRoleSelected}
      ...
    />
    <Button label="search" disabled={!isRoleSelected} />
    <Button label="reset" onClick={() => setIsRoleSelected(false)} />
  </FormProvider>
);
```

In SearchRole.jsx:

```js
onChange={(_, data) => {
  onChange(data);
  setIsSelected(!!data);
}}
```